# How to keep only the most recent revised order for each order in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a data frame that tracks the order number, and the revision number for that order in two different columns like so:

```
OrderNum  RevNum  TotalPrice
 0AXL3     0       $5.00
 0AXL3     1       $4.00
 0AXL3     2       $7.00
 0AXL3     3       $8.00
 0BDF1     0       $3.00
 0BDF1     1       $2.50
 0BDF1     2       $8.50
```

The result we want is a new data frame that only has the most recent version of each order, so :

```
OrderNum  RevNum  TotalPrice
 0AXL3     3       $8.00
 0BDF1     2       $8.50
```

Is there a quick way to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [100]: df.groupby('OrderNum', as_index=False).last()
Out[100]:
  OrderNum  RevNum TotalPrice
0    0AXL3       3      $8.00
1    0BDF1       2      $8.50
```

**UPDATE:**

> If there were other columns in the data frame, would this keep those
>   as well?

```
In [116]: df['new'] = np.arange(len(df))

In [117]: df
Out[117]:
  OrderNum  RevNum TotalPrice  new
0    0AXL3       0      $5.00    0
1    0AXL3       1      $4.00    1
2    0AXL3       2      $7.00    2
3    0AXL3       3      $8.00    3
4    0BDF1       0      $3.00    4
5    0BDF1       1      $2.50    5
6    0BDF1       2      $8.50    6

In [118]: df.groupby('OrderNum', as_index=False).last()
Out[118]:
  OrderNum  RevNum TotalPrice  new
0    0AXL3       3      $8.00    3
1    0BDF1       2      $8.50    6
```

Comment: Thank you! If there were other columns in the data frame, would this keep those as well? Sorry - super new to python

Answer (score 1):

One way is use drop_duplicates, note dataframe should be sorted on RevNum from smallest to largest or you can add sort_values:

```
df1.drop_duplicates(subset='OrderNum', keep='last')
```

Output:

```
  OrderNum  RevNum TotalPrice
3    0AXL3       3      $8.00
6    0BDF1       2      $8.50
```

OR

```
df1[~df1.duplicated(subset='OrderNum', keep='last')]
```

Output:

```
  OrderNum  RevNum TotalPrice
3    0AXL3       3      $8.00
6    0BDF1       2      $8.50
```