# How to create a new column stating if this row is the most recent revised order for each order in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

Say I had the following dataframe capturing an Order's number, the revision number to that same order, and the total price:

```
OrderNum  RevNum  TotalPrice
 0AXL3     0       $5.00
 0AXL3     1       $4.00
 0AXL3     2       $7.00
 0AXL3     3       $8.00
 0BDF1     0       $3.00
 0BDF1     1       $2.50
 0BDF1     2       $8.50
```

How would I go about adding a column that states whether or not this row is the most recent revision to the order? The Desired Output would be as follows:

```
OrderNum  RevNum  TotalPrice  NewestRevision
 0AXL3     0       $5.00      No
 0AXL3     1       $4.00      No
 0AXL3     2       $7.00      No
 0AXL3     3       $8.00      Yes
 0BDF1     0       $3.00      No
 0BDF1     1       $2.50      No
 0BDF1     2       $8.50      Yes
```

Note this is very similar to a previous question that I had asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216128/how-to-keep-only-the-most-recent-revised-order-for-each-order-in-pandas)

however rather than removing the previous entries, we now just want a new column stating whether or not this is the newest revision. Thank you in advance for any / all help!!

**edit: The rows in my dataframe are not necessarily sorted by OrderNum**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Wen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49802378/2074981) below is great if your rows are always sorted so the last row in each group is the latest revision.

If that's not the case, and assuming that "newest revision" is equivalent to having the highest `RevNum` in the group, you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
df['NewestRevision'] = np.where( \
    df.RevNum == df.groupby('OrderNum')['RevNum'].transform(np.max), 'Yes', 'No')
```

This checks whether the `RevNum` is the same as the highest `RevNum` for a given `OrderNum`, and if so returns `'Yes'` and otherwise returns `'No'`.

Comment: Yes, to clarify in my dataframe the rows are not always as cleanly sorted as in my example. I should have edited it to reflect that.

Answer (score 4):

You can using `duplicated` with `map`

```
df['NewestRevision']=df.duplicated('OrderNum',keep='last').map({True:'No',False:'Yes'})
df
Out[328]: 
  OrderNum  RevNum TotalPrice NewestRevision
0    0AXL3       0      $5.00             No
1    0AXL3       1      $4.00             No
2    0AXL3       2      $7.00             No
3    0AXL3       3      $8.00            Yes
4    0BDF1       0      $3.00             No
5    0BDF1       1      $2.50             No
6    0BDF1       2      $8.50            Yes
```

Comment: Does this assume a sorted dataframe?

Comment: @chrisz yes it will assume the order entry

Comment: Thank you for your answer, apologies in my example I had the dataframe sorted however this is not always the case.